# How can I use the qsort() function with this struct?

Tags: c

I have these structs,

```
    typedef struct
{
  char *str; //register to store each element (one string)

} v_elemento;

/**
* this register has an array of elements, a counter for the size and another for the capacity
*/
typedef struct
{
  /** numero de elementos do vetor */
  int tamanho; //size

  /** capacidade do vetor */
  int capacidade; //capacity

  /** array of stored elements */
  v_elemento* elementos;

} vetor;
```

I heard that there is a qsort() function that allows me to sort an array, I tried checking the internet but all examples either use int, float or strings.  How can I use the qsort() function using the structures above?

I want something like this

```
   for(int i=0; i<vetor->tamanho;i++)
//sorts vetor->elemento[i].str
```

This is my cmp function;

```
int compara(v_elemento *p0,v_elemento *p1){
      return strcmp(p0->str,p1->str);
}
```

This is my qsort() function:

```
qsort(vec->elementos,vec->tamanho, sizeof(v_elemento),compara)
```

Im gonna show you a code, which is working properly, it sorts what I want but it's selection sort:

```
int vetor_ordena_sel(vetor* vec)
{

        //special cases
        if(vec==NULL)
            return -1;
        if(vec->tamanho<=1) // already sorted
            return 0;
        // special cases

        int i, j, posicao; //posicao is position

        char *min_tmp;

        for(i=0;i<(vec->tamanho);i++){
            posicao=i;
            for(j=i+1;j<(vec->tamanho);j++){
                if(strcmp(vec->elementos[j].str,vec->elementos[posicao].str)<0)
                    posicao=j;
            }


                if(posicao!=i){
                    min_tmp=vec->elementos[i].str;
                    vec->elementos[i].str=vec->elementos[posicao].str;
                    vec->elementos[posicao].str=min_tmp;
                }
        }

                    return 0;
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Which array do you want to sort? Your code doesn't contain any arrays, just two types.

Comment: You can use it on whatever you want as long as you are providing a proper comparison function.

Comment: I've edited my original post, it shows now what I want to sort.

Comment: The actual documentation of `qsort()` -- [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) for instance -- would be a good place to start.  Observe that the arguments are, in order, a pointer to the first element of the array, the number of elements in the array, the size of each element, and a pointer to a comparison function with which to compare elements.  It works exactly the same regardless of the types of the array elements (consult the examples you've found for guidance); you just have to be sure to provide a comparison function appropriate for that type.

Comment: `vetor->elemento[i].str` is a char pointer, possibly pointing to one single string. Is that what you want to sort? You want to sort a string?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to sort, the array of strings alphabetically.

Comment: I suspect `vec->elementos` or its elements are not correctly populated.  Post a minimal example of code that is working as best you have now.

Comment: I edited my post, I posted a selection sort function that's working properly so it gives you an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing comparison function for builtin sort functions, the pass in parameter should really be `const void *` instead of any other type. Please refer to documentation.

I don't know the difference between "capacity" and "size" in that struct, but as you use the size variable in qsort, I'll do the same.

The following comparator works under gcc 4.2.1.

```
int compara(const void *p0, const void *p1)
{
    return strcmp(((v_elemento *)p0)->str, ((v_elemento *)p1)->str);
}
```

As I said above, you should only pass in `const void *`, so I made a type casting.

Below is the driver code I wrote:

```
// Test case.
vetor *vec = malloc(sizeof(vetor));
vec->tamanho = 5;
vec->elementos = malloc(5 * sizeof(v_elemento));
vec->elementos[0].str = "This";
vec->elementos[1].str = "is";
vec->elementos[2].str = "a";
vec->elementos[3].str = " test";
vec->elementos[4].str = "string.";

// Sort.
qsort(vec->elementos, vec->tamanho, sizeof(v_elemento), compara);

// Print result.
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    printf("%s\n", vec->elementos[i].str);
}

// Clean up.
free(vec->elementos);
free(vec);
```

And the output result is:

```
 test
This
a
is
string.
```

Note that there is a space in the string ranked first. :-)

Comment: It fixed the problem for me. I am very grateful! Thank you!